# Error with the icon of my app in XP

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-xp, designer, ctype

I've done two apps in Win7 x64 with VS2012, but when I try to run it in XP I was getting an unknown error when trying to open the apps.

Finally I found the problem and is in this line generated by the designer in the **Main.Designer.vb**:

```
Me.Icon = CType(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon"), System.Drawing.Icon)
```

(If I delete the line then all is OK in XP)

I always select the TitleBar icon by clicking on the "Icon" property field in the form properties.

I have some questions about this...

1. How I can modify that line to still showing my icon and working in XP?
2. Everytime that I put an Icon to the titlebar of my form then I need to manually modify that line to work in XP?
3. Why Microsoft is so silly to make incompatible with XP it's own generated code of the designer? (don't need to answer this)

Comment: What version of the .Net framework is installed on your XP machine?

Comment: 4.0 on XP but I've tested too with 3.0, 3.5 changing the FW version from the properties project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the form icon at runtime to try and get round this.

- Add an icon your your project resources call it `ApplicationIcon`
- In `Form_Load` add:
- `Me.Icon = My.Resources.ApplicationIcon`

Comment: a little question, I need to add the resource as an Image or as an "Other" or no matter

Comment: I ask that because an icon is an index of images each with different size all in one recipient, don't know exactly if I need to add it as an Image or Other.

Comment: @ElektroHacker - You need to add the resource as an Icon (file should be a valid .ico file)

Comment: That is not solving my problem, I'm still getting the error with my icon in XP even if I try your solution... Maybe the problem is cause the icon layers but don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. It was related to having a column `.Name` property in a DataGridView set as "Icon". When I changed the column name to "TypeIcon" the problem was resolved. Perhaps using reserved words as DataGridViewColumn names should be avoided.